# Skill points available at Character Creation with Savage Culture

Tags: character-creation, blade-of-the-iron-throne

Just started a session of Blade of the Iron Throne, looks good and I have only just rolled my character.

During the character creation you choose a culture, I chose savage. I read the bonuses you get as useful on the attributes, but I was wondering about the statement where you get +5 skill on Animal Ken etc. Is that per skill or just an extra 5 points to spread over the relevant skills?

I am currently reading this as +5 extra to spread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the exact wording under Savage Cultures, from pg. 24:

> 5 bonus skill points related to Survival, Climbing, Animal Ken, etc.

I read this as 5 points to spread.

The only area which seems open to interpretation is the "etc." which I see as being "If you can justify it making sense to your GM about whether a certain skill should or shouldn't also be included based on your culture".

Comment: I think this gives a bit of freedom, if you can argue the case for lock picking... If you were planning on survival anyway that is useful as you get that skill for free then.